# Is there a more idiomatic way to initialize this map in Kotlin?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, initialization

I am writing a small game, and part of that is to keep track of player's scores. For this, I have a map initialized as follows:

```
// given: players: List<Player>
var scores: MutableMap<Player, Int> = mutableMapOf(*players.map { it to 0 }.toTypedArray())
```

**What bothers me is that i need to use `.toTypedArray()`** on the result of the `map { it to 0 }` before I can apply the spread operator `*`. Is there a way to avoid this? The same problem also occurs when creating a map by zipping two arrays:

```
// does not compile:
mapOf(*a1.zip(a2))

// works but more verbose:
mapOf(*a1.zip(a2).toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `associate` function can also help with solving your problem and looks even better imho:

```
val scores: MutableMap<Player, Int> = players.associate { it to 0 }.toMutableMap()
```

And the zipping is even easier:

```
val zipped = a1.zip(a2).toMap()
```

Comment: You can also use `.toMap` on the result of zipping: `(a1 zip a2).toMap()`

Answer (score 7):

```
val pointsByPlayer = players.map { it to 0 }.toMap(mutableMapOf())
```

That said, a better design would probably to simply have a mutable `points` property in the Player class.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. The `zip` case becomes even more elegant: `a1.zip(a2).toMap()`

Comment: You could still wrap it into your own Player class, with properties delegating to the external Player class.